# How to dynamically select a class property based on the argument of a method

Tags: typescript

I have the following class:

```
class Person { 
  name: string;
  address: string;
  color: string;
    
  addParameterValue(parameterName: string, value: string){
    if (parameterName == 'name'){
      this.name = value;
    }
    if (parameterName == 'address'){
      this.address = value;
    }
  }
}
```

I need to make this more dynamically, not an long if-statement, in such way that

```
const person = new Person()
person.addParameterValue('color', 'blue')
console.log(person.color) //'blue'
```

I have tried a couple of code snippets like

```
this[parameterName] = value;
```

But it gives the following error

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Person'.

Code snippet suggested by @jonrsharpe implemented:

```
addParameterValue(parameterName: keyof Person, value: string){
        this[parameterName] = value
}
```

gives the following error (but might be a step in the right direction):

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(parameterName: keyof Person, value: string) => void'.

Comment: Are you looking for `keyof Person`? The error is correct - not all strings are valid property names. Also note the code you've posted isn't a valid class definition.

Comment: Updated the class, so it is now a valid class definition.

Comment: With your latest revision note that not all props of a Person have string values - one of them, addParameterValue itself, is a function. You can `Exclude` this, use a mapped type to leave it out, make the type of the second parameter depend on the type of the named property, ...

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is this, group the properties into an object which is indexable. However, I have to say that whatever it is you're doing to me would be indicative of messy or bad code. You probably should just do the if statement, sure it's longer but it's clearer what you're doing. Even better would be getting rid of `addParamterValue` all together and just having functions `setName`, `setAddress`, `setColor`.

Code doesn't have to be short, it has to be clear. If you do things like this all the time your code will become difficult to refactor, difficult to build on, and difficult for others to understand.

```
type Keys = "name" | "address" | "color";

type Properties = {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  color: string;
}

class Person  { 
  props: Properties;

  constructor(name: string, address: string, color: string) {
    this.props = {name, address, color};
  }
    
  addParameterValue(parameterName: keyof Properties, value: string){
    this.props[parameterName] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Agreeing with the fact that code should be good, not short. However the class has currently 14 parameters. And I want to iterate over a dictionary to fill the class. The dictionary looks like: {name: 'Ben', address: 'Scotland', color: 'purple', number: '981', ...}, so using individual methods feels odd.

Also, unfortunately I am not able to change the parameters due to the use of the class (it is already implemented in existing code which I can not change.)

Comment: @Jasper, there is a good chance then that this means you should actually have multiple classes. Some of these properties are probably related and should be grouped. Google "single responsibility principle" and "large class code smell": https://refactoring.guru/smells/large-class. 14 properties indicates to me at least that your class is doing multiple things, you could maybe extract a `ContactInfo` class containing email, phone, etc. a `DateOfBirth` class that has a DOB and a method `getAge`.

Comment: Also, if you want a dictionary, then you can just use a dictionary if that is helpful. I still think if some of the properties are related then they should be grouped, you may just not need a class and could instead get away with `type Person = { properties you want grouped appropriately } `

Comment: Agreeing. I am updating legacy code and maybe I need a bigger overhaul then I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can access an object parameter in multiple ways, this method works in your case:

```js
class Person {
    addParameterValue(parameterName: string, value: string) {
        this[parameterName] = value
    }
}
const person = new Person()
person.addParameterValue('color', 'blue')
console.log(person['color'])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. The logging is different, but unfortunatelly the method still doesn't work.